# Plaid Integration on Salesforce site page

Tags: force.com-sites, iframe

I have a requirement to integrate with Plaid from a Salesforce Site page. Below is the snippet from their documentation that I am embedding to my site VF page:

```
(async function() {

  const configs = {

    token: '{!link_token}',

    onSuccess: async function(public_token, metadata) {

      // The onSuccess function is called when the user has successfully
      // authenticated and selected an account to use.
      await fetch('/get_access_token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ public_token: public_token }),
      });
    },
    onExit: async function(err, metadata) {
      // 2b. Gracefully handle the invalid link token error. A link token
      // can become invalidated if it expires, has already been used
      // for a link session, or is associated with too many invalid logins.
      if (err != null && err.error_code === 'INVALID_LINK_TOKEN') {
        linkHandler.destroy();
        linkHandler = Plaid.create({
          ...configs,
          token: await fetchLinkToken(),
        });
      }
      if (err != null) {
        // Handle any other types of errors.
      }
      // metadata contains information about the institution that the
      // user selected and the most recent API request IDs.
      // Storing this information can be helpful for support.
    },
  };

  var linkHandler = Plaid.create(configs);

  document.getElementById('j_id0:frm:link-button').onclick = function() {
    linkHandler.open();
  };
})();
```

Link token is generated by making a callout in my apex controller. The javascript uses the token to render a webpage from plaid in an iframe. At this point, the site page opens the iframe and immediately closes it. When I add this to a simple HTML the iframe renders correctly. I have added the iframe domain as a trusted domain for my site and set Clickjack Protection Level to 'Allow framing of site or community pages on external domains (Good protection)'. I even tested by setting it to 'Allow framing by any page (No protection)' but it still exhibits same behavior. Any thoughts on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured the answer! It had to do with the default submit action of the commandbutton that was reloading the page. Changing to commandlink fixed it.